# CSS - create two columns

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my school project. I want to make two columns on my page using css, but nothing is working...

Website : http://kitlab.pef.czu.cz/~wbdinfo141528/
CSS : http://kitlab.pef.czu.cz/~wbdinfo141528/css/style.css

I hope that there is some dumb mistake, but I can't figure out, where the problem is.

I want to place the right column next to the left one : [image]

Comment: Include your code here ....

Comment: `margin` set to 500px

Comment: Your whole css structure is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your margin was taking up the entire row, that's why the second `div` was pushed down. You don't need margin, just set the width and display it as an inline-block. The `inline-block` means it'll still be a block, but will wrap like text - so if there's enough space for the second div to be in the same row as the first, it can be.

Replace CSS with this, comments for what was changed.

```
div.leva {
    background: blueviolet;
    /* float: left; */
    /* margin: 5px 500px auto auto; */
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.prava {
    background: yellow;
    /* float: left; */
    /* margin: 5px auto auto 500px; */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a relative container div and set that to 100%, and have two absolute divs inside the container with 50% width.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftdiv"></div>
    <div class="rightdiv"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.leftdiv, .rightdiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    top: 0;
}

.leftdiv {
    left: 0;
}

.rightdiv {
    right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add `margin:0` in div leva et prava  http://jsfiddle.net/rvp5js2w/

Answer (score 0):

At first glance your floats are incorrect.

The purple is floated right while the yellow is floated left.

Set a width (where width is less then total width of stranka/2) for each of these div's and then float them correctly and it should line up.